# looping over multiPhylo: why does "1:length(trees)" work?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a question about for-loops and lists/multiPhylo-objects. I've actually solved the issue at hand, but I don't understand why the solution I applied worked. I'd love to know why it worked so that I can understand things better.

goal: use a for-loop to apply a particular function to every tree in a multiPhylo object, write each tree to file.

The particular set of trees I'm looping over happen to be accessible publicly via GitHub, so you can have a look yourself if you'd like.

```
library(ape)

#reading in data
fn <- "https://github.com/D-PLACE/dplace-data/blob/master/phylogenies/gray_et_al2009/original/a400-m1pcv-time.trees.gz"

trees <- read.nexus(fn)
```

The particular function I want to apply is just `ape::drop.tip()`. I'm doing a prune in two stages, but for the sake of the reprex let's just say I want to drop one tip from each tree - "Sisingga". I would have imagined that code chunk (a) below would work, but it doesn't. Instead (b) works. Why?

```
tip_to_drop <- "Sisingga"

index <- 0 #starting a count to have something to name files with uniquely

#code chunk a

for(tree in trees){
  
  index <- index +1
  
  tree <- ape::drop.tip(tree, tip_to_drop)
  
  output_fn <- paste0("tree_",  index, ".txt") #making unique file name
  write.nexus(tree,file = output_fn )
}

index <- 0

#code chunk b

for(tree in 1:length(trees)){

index <- index +1

tree <- trees[[tree]]
tree <- ape::drop.tip(tree, tip_to_drop)

output_fn <- paste0("tree_",  index, ".txt")
write.nexus(tree,file = output_fn )
}
```

I'm happy that I've solved my problem, but I'm left a bit confused. Any light would be welcome.

p.s. the reason I thought chunk (a) would work is because it has in the past in a similar situation, but with another multiPhylo object. In that case it was https://cdstar.shh.mpg.de/bitstreams/EAEA0-D501-DBB8-65C4-0/tree_glottolog_newick.txt.

Comment: Interestingly, when I run `read.nexus(fn)`, I get `Error in start:end : argument of length 0`. Are there any additional steps needed?

Comment: @slamballais I found I needed to download the file and load it from my computer, having got the same error.

Comment: Reducing the example further, `for (t in trees[1]) str(t)` gives a different result to `str(trees[[1]])` which seems surprising

Comment: If this doesn't get an answer here in a reasonable time, it might be worth raising an issue on the associated [github](https://github.com/emmanuelparadis/ape/issues) which seems to be actively maintained.

Comment: yes sorry, I have the file on my machine and I didn't realise the URL to read.nexus() wouldn't work until now. @miff is right it should be fine if you download the file first.

Comment: @Miff
I work with the people who maintain the GitHub repos, I just thought this was more of an R issue than an issue with the file per see. But I can raise it with them too.

Comment: @Miff to make things weirder, try `sapply(trees[1], str)`, which matches `trees[[1]]`. @Laserhedvig I think it has to do with the way that `[.multiPhylo` and `[[.multiPhylo` are defined, and how a `for`-loop interacts with those.

Comment: Yes I had a play with apply too. My hypothesis is that the TipLabel of the multiPhylo is stored as an attribute to the whole list, then `[[` adds it to the individual phylo object. The for loop seems to do something different in how it treats the multiPhylo as a "vector-like" object that doesn't directly use the `[[.multiPhylo`, but I'm not sure what, hence not an answer.